# Sort a Matrix by a specific column (with 2-digits numbers or more)

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I want to sort a numpy matrix by the order of its first column numbers (the command have to move all the row of each element of this column), I tried to use the "argsort()" command, but it doesn't work well when the numbers are upper than 9, because it works only with the first digit of each element, for example for the following numpy matrix:

```
1.1 ....... ........ .......
1.2 ....... ........ .......
1.3 ....... ........ .......
2.1 ....... ........ .......
2.2 ....... ........ .......
2.3 ....... ........ .......
3.1 ....... ........ .......
3.2 ....... ........ .......
3.3 ....... ........ .......
6.1 ....... ........ .......
6.2 ....... ........ .......
6.3 ....... ........ .......
8.1 ....... ........ .......
8.2 ....... ........ .......
8.3 ....... ........ .......
5.1 ....... ........ .......
5.2 ....... ........ .......
5.3 ....... ........ .......
4.1 ....... ........ .......
4.2 ....... ........ .......
4.3 ....... ........ .......
12.1 ....... ........ .......
12.2 ....... ........ .......
12.3 ....... ........ .......
11.1 ....... ........ .......
11.2 ....... ........ .......
11.3 ....... ........ .......
10.1 ....... ........ .......
10.2 ....... ........ .......
10.3 ....... ........ .......
9.1 ....... ........ .......
9.2 ....... ........ .......
9.3 ....... ........ .......
7.1 ....... ........ .......
7.2 ....... ........ .......

cjarray.sort=cjarray[cjarray[:, 0].argsort()]

1.1 ....... ........ ....... 
1.2 ....... ........ ....... 
1.3 ....... ........ ....... 
10.1 ....... ........ ....... 
10.2 ....... ........ ....... 
10.3 ....... ........ ....... 
11.1 ....... ........ ....... 
11.2 ....... ........ ....... 
11.3 ....... ........ ....... 
12.1 ....... ........ ....... 
12.2 ....... ........ ....... 
12.3 ....... ........ ....... 
2.1 ....... ........ ....... 
2.2 ....... ........ ....... 
2.3 ....... ........ ....... 
3.1 ....... ........ ....... 
3.2 ....... ........ ....... 
3.3 ....... ........ ....... 
4.1 ....... ........ ....... 
4.2 ....... ........ ....... 
4.3 ....... ........ ....... 
5.1 ....... ........ ....... 
5.2 ....... ........ ....... 
5.3 ....... ........ ....... 
6.1 ....... ........ ....... 
6.2 ....... ........ ....... 
6.3 ....... ........ ....... 
7.1 ....... ........ ....... 
7.2 ....... ........ ....... 
7.3 ....... ........ ....... 
8.1 ....... ........ ....... 
8.2 ....... ........ ....... 
8.3 ....... ........ ....... 
9.1 ....... ........ ....... 
9.2 ....... ........ .......
```

As you can see, the matrix jumps from 1.3 to 10.1 because the command only concerned about the first digit, can somebody give a hand.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Hopefully someone will be along to answer your question.  While not bad, you could improve your question by reducing the size of the example output to be the minimum needed to show your problem, and by posting the code that you have used, to give us a better idea of what you tried, and a starting point for suggestions for change.

Comment: can you print the dtype of the matrix? I think it's str?

Answer (score 1):

You should `argsort()` only that column along which you want to **sort** the matrix and use the generated **indices** to **sort** the matrix. Demo:

```
>>> a=np.array([[12,2,3,4],[22,1,3,5],[4,1,6,7],[15,1,2,7]])
>>> a
array([[12,  2,  3,  4],
       [22,  1,  3,  5],
       [ 4,  1,  6,  7],
       [15,  1,  2,  7]])
>>> a[a[:,0].argsort()]
array([[ 4,  1,  6,  7],
       [12,  2,  3,  4],
       [15,  1,  2,  7],
       [22,  1,  3,  5]])
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! I used the same structure: cjarraysort=cjarray[cjarray[:, 0].argsort()] but doesn't work, it bring me the out above.

Comment: I think either you are using **numpy matrix** or you have **string** values in the matrix. So convert your matrix first using `cjarray=np.array(cjarray,dtype=float)' and try the same code again. I hope this will help you.

Comment: It is a:                                                            >>> type(cjarray)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>                                                    I have the following error using your structure,         Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\borrar.py", line 35, in <module>
    cjarray=np.array(cjarray,dtype=float)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: +j -0.9383000267 The first columm of the matrix are the numbers above at the original question and the other columms are the part real and imaginary of complex numbers.

Comment: You know a way to convert to float only the first columm? I tried with cjarray[:][0] but doesn't work! I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Yes, you can do it like this, `a[np.array(a[:,0],dtype=float).argsort()]`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used for a long time to emulate MATLAB `sortrows`. Tbh `.argsort` seems more appealing and should work just fine. It was not available a couple of years ago.

```
def sortrows(data):
    """assumes data to be numpy.ndarray"""
    data = np.ascontinuousarray(data)
    return np.sort(
        data.view(['', data.dtype] * data.shape[1]), axis=0
    ).view(data.dtype)
```